# Mapbox change icon when onclick

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a list of branches that will be displayed on the map. When user click on the marker, it will open a detail window. But i also wish to change the marker icon upon clicked. Not sure how to go about it, but this is what i have done.

```
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWF0aGlhc2xveSerfIsImEiOiJjamNibG1tNGcwNHMxMzNuZGFtOWY3eWxtyergds5In0.sTTa8hwjoXWCxa2uVHgE5Q';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'LocatorMap', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
    center: [103.851959, 1.290270], // starting position
    zoom: 11.5
});


// add markers to map
poolbranches.features.forEach(function(marker) {

  // create a HTML element for each feature
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = 'bluemarker';
  var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
    .setHTML('<div class="popup-branch-name">'+ marker.properties.name + '</div>' + '<div class="popup-branch-address">' + marker.properties.address + '</div>'
    + '<div class="outlet-control">' +
        '<button class="detail"><span class="btn-txt">DETAILS</span></button>' +
        '<button class="distance"><span class="btn-txt">3.3 KM</span></button>' +
        '<button class="direction"><span class="btn-txt">GET DIRECTION</span><span class="icon-arrow-right"></span></button>' +
      '</div>');
  // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
  new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
  .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
  .setPopup(popup)// sets a popup on this marker
  .addTo(map);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Is my explanation of the question not clear?

Comment: you can add a click event listener to the marker when it's created and then use `Marker#getElement` to access the HTMLElement and change the CSS or HTML to display the new icon you want.